# How to extract files names read and written by a python script without executing the script itself?

Tags: python, eval, static-analysis

I want to analyse a collection of python files. These files are from the same project, they read a file and write to a file. Now certain files can only be run after running some other file since it takes the output of the previous file as input. I want to visualize the dependancies. To do this, I would like to extract the input file name and output file name from a given file without executing the file itself. How best to accomplish this task?

To get more concrete:

I have python files with statements such as these:

```
base_dir = os.path.join('/bla/bla/infiles') 
in_file  = open(os.path.join(base_dir, 'input.json'))
out_file = open(os.path.join(base_dir, 'output.json'), 'w')
```

I need to scan the file and get only these variables out (the ones that seem to be file names) and print the evaluated values out.

thank you for your help.

Comment: Ouch, that'd be a tough act to do generically. A dynamic language has countless opportunities to alter the flow of code and assemble arguments to the `open()` function. Your best bet is to wrap the `open()` function and track what arguments are passed in *while running the code*.

Comment: Martijn is pretty right; you can't do this well in general.   A cheesy solution: Simply pick out all literal strings, and see which ones match files names on your system.  This won't catch dynamically constructed file names or those read from other sources, but it will work for your example.

Comment: thank you Martijn, Ira. I had an inkling this might be difficult, anyway Cheesy solutions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply import the files in question, and read out the variables.

put all you functionality in a function to make sure nothing is run and use the

```
__main__
```

directive to be able to execute from shell

```
import os
import sys

base_dir = os.path.join('/bla/bla/infiles')

def hest(args*):
    print args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hest(sys.argv)
```

if you import the above from an other python script, you can access base_dir but the function hest is not run. If you run the script from a shell, hest will be run.

To make it even prettier, you should wrap it in a class I think.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open the file for reading:

```
with open("file.ext", "r") as ifile:
    data = ifile.read()
```

Then write regex or whatever you prefer to find the filenames.